# CGAL Solves a Quadratic Programming

Tags: cgal

I have a qp problem:

```
Minimize: -5x0 - x1 - 4x2 - 5x5 + 1000x0x2 + 1000x1x2 + 1000x0x3 
      + 1000x1x3 + 1000x0x4 +1000x1x4

Subject to: x0>=0 x1>=0 x2>=0 x3>=0 x4>=0 x5>=0
        x0+x1+x5<=5      
        x2+x3+x4<=5
```

The answer should be X0=0 X1=0 X2=5 X3=0 X4=0 X5=5 and obj=-45.

But CGAL gives me    X0=5 X1=0 X2=0 X3=0 X4=0 X5=0 and obj=-25.

The code is pasted as follows:

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Kelly

```
#include <iostream>
#include <climits>
#include <cassert>
#include <CGAL/basic.h>
#include <CGAL/QP_models.h>
#include <CGAL/QP_functions.h>
// choose exact integral type
#ifdef CGAL_USE_GMP
#include <CGAL/Gmpz.h>
typedef CGAL::Gmpz ET;
#else
#include <CGAL/MP_Float.h>
typedef CGAL::MP_Float ET;
#endif

using namespace std;

// program and solution types
typedef CGAL::Quadratic_program<int> Program;
typedef CGAL::Quadratic_program_solution<ET> Solution;

int
main(){
    Program qp (CGAL::SMALLER, true, 0.0, false, 0.0);

    qp.set_c(0, -5);
    qp.set_c(1, -1);
    qp.set_c(2, -4);
    qp.set_c(5, -5);

    int g = 1000;
    qp.set_d(2, 0, g);
    qp.set_d(2, 1, g);
    qp.set_d(3, 0, g);
    qp.set_d(3, 1, g);
    qp.set_d(4, 0, g);
    qp.set_d(4, 1, g);

    int nRow = 0;
    qp.set_a(0, nRow,  1.0);
    qp.set_a(1, nRow,  1.0);
    qp.set_a(5, nRow,  1.0);
    qp.set_b(nRow, 5);

    nRow++;
    qp.set_a(2, nRow,  1.0);
    qp.set_a(3, nRow,  1.0);
    qp.set_a(4, nRow,  1.0);
    qp.set_b(nRow, 5);

    Solution s = CGAL::solve_quadratic_program(qp, ET());
    assert (s.solves_quadratic_program(qp));
    CGAL::print_nonnegative_quadratic_program(std::cout, qp, "first_qp");

    std::cout << s;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hi. Your question has not been answered, so far. I suggest you post a link to it in the CGAL-discuss mailing list, to try reaching more audience. I am a CGAL developer myself, but I do not know anything about the QP solver.

Answer (score 0):

Since you matrix `D` (quadratic objective function) is not positive semi-definite, your result isn't so surprising. CGAL does not guarantee convergence towards a global minimum but towards a local one. What you obtain is a local minimum respecting the constraints you imposed.

If you set minimum bounds for `x2` and `x5` at 1 by writing `qp.set_l(2,true,1); qp.set_l(5,true,1);`, you will see that you converge towards the solution that you computed.